# What are meaning of these short words?. (return value from google finance)

Tags: stock, stockquotes, google-finance

The return data from http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NASDAQ%3aGOOG is

{
"id": "304466804484872" ,
"t" : "GOOG" ,
"e" : "NASDAQ" ,
"l" : "525.02" ,
"l_fix" : "525.02" ,
"l_cur" : "525.02" ,
"s": "2" ,
"ltt":"4:47PM EDT" ,
"lt" : "Jul 7, 4:47PM EDT" ,
"lt_dts" : "2015-07-07T16:47:00Z" ,
"c" : "+2.16" ,
"c_fix" : "2.16" ,
"cp" : "0.41" ,
"cp_fix" : "0.41" ,
"ccol" : "chg" ,
"pcls_fix" : "522.86" ,
"el": "524.00" ,
"el_fix": "524.00" ,
"el_cur": "524.00" ,
"elt" : "Jul 7, 5:43PM EDT" ,
"ec" : "-1.02" ,
"ec_fix" : "-1.02" ,
"ecp" : "-0.19" ,
"ecp_fix" : "-0.19" ,
"eccol" : "chr" ,
"div" : "" ,
"yld" : "" 
}
What are meaning of these short words, 
t, e, l, l_fix, l_cur, s, ltt, lt, lt_dts, c, c_fix, cp, cp_fix, ccol, pcls_fix, el, el_fix, el_cur, elt, ec, ec_fix, ecp, ecp_fix, eccol, div, yld ?
Thank you.

Comment: Google Finance API is deprecated; you should not be developing against it. Use one of the alternatives, such as [Yahoo Finance](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22GOOG%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys).

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same answer, and found the following:

- **Credits** Mitra Sekhar Dora

> **id** : Internal Google Security ID
>
> **t** : Ticker
>
> **e** : Exchange Name
>
> **l** : Last Price
>
> **l_cur** : ???
>
> **ltt** : Last Trade Time
>
> **ltt** : Last Trade Date/Time
>
> **c** : Change (in ccy) - formatted with +/-   cp : Change (%)
>
> **ccol** :
>
> **el** : Last Price in Extended Hours Trading
>
> **el_cur** :
>
> **elt**: Last Trade Date/Time in Extended Hours Trading
>
> **ec** : Extended Hours Change (in ccy) - formatted with +/-
>
> **ec** : Extended Hours Change (%)
>
> **eccol** :